# Remote debugging with debugpy works from code but not from command line

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a python binary (which is built using `bazel` but I don't think that's relevant) that I can run like this:

```
$ bazel-bin/path/to/my_test

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.228s

OK
```

I want to use `debugpy` to debug this binary in Visual Studio Code. I can go the file I want to debug and add

```
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

Build and run the binary, it starts waiting for the client, then I use this vscode config

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 5678,
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything works fine. I can put breakpoints, jump around the code, perfect.

Now, if instead of adding the code at top, I do:

```
python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 --wait-for-client bazel-bin/path/to/my_test
```

It looks like the client is waiting for connections. Then I start remote debugging on vscode and... nothing happens. The debugger starts and finishes in a second. I see no logs, no errors.

Where can I find logs to see what's going on on either the client side or vscode?

Comment: Got the same issue. It just seems like that feature doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a breakpoint?

`debugpy.breakpoint()`

```
import debugpy

# 5678 is the default attach port in the VS Code debug configurations. Unless a host and port are specified, host defaults to 127.0.0.1
debugpy.listen(5678)
print("Waiting for debugger attach")
debugpy.wait_for_client()
debugpy.breakpoint() #must have
print('break on this line')
```

Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Well, part of the reason to run debugpy via `python -m debugpy` is to avoid modifying the source files. It also doesn't change anything, it still isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a breakpoint in the Python source file before attach to the debugpy server, then it will hit and break back into VSCode after attach.

Comment: No breakpoint will ever be hit, since the code never starts. It just waits for connections, and closes all incoming connections the instant they arrive.