# Attaching debugger to nemo python

Tags: python, debugging, vscode-debugger, linux-mint

Under Linux Mint 21, I am trying to debug python script embedded in `nemo` (for example, like the `nemo-terminal` package which is written in Python). I followed instruction from [debugpy doc](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy) and other SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690653/remote-debugging-with-debugpy-works-from-code-but-not-from-command-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013251/debugging-python-in-docker-container-using-debugpy-and-vs-code-results-in-timeou).

My python script is located at `/usr/share/nemo-python/extensions/mytest.py`. I copied the `debugpy` module in the same directory (so that it is accessible as an import) then at the start of my script, I added

```
import debugpy 
debugpy.listen(('127.0.0.1', 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

When launching nemo from terminal, it gets hanging waiting for connection.

Then from VSCode, I created a `launch.json`

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5678,
    }
]
```

When I start debugging, I get an error `RuntimeError: Can't listen for client connections: [Errno 98] Adress already in use` before even reaching the first breakpoint.

Full trace is

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/phil/Personnalisation/Nemo/nemo-python extensions/mytest.py", line 23, in <module>
    debugpy.listen(('127.0.0.18', 5679))
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/public_api.py", line 31, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 143, in debug
    log.reraise_exception("{0}() failed:", func.__name__, level="info")
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 141, in debug
    return func(address, settrace_kwargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phil/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.2.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/api.py", line 262, in listen
    raise RuntimeError(str(endpoints["error"]))
RuntimeError: Can't listen for client connections: [Errno 98] Adresse déjà utilisée
```

How should I run a debugger for nemo's python extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was unrelated to nemo.

The launch.json was ok. The script was ok. I was just not using the right debug script, e.g. on vscode, under "run and debug", you should select the debug script to be used.